# C#: How to stop my program until a button is clicked

Tags: c#, event-handling

I start a program loop with a click on `Button1`. The loop is executed in the Click-Event-Handler of `Button1`.

My requirement:

The loop shall stop every time at a certain point in code and wait for Button2 to be pressed before execution goes on.

I tried:

```
private ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

and in my `Button1` Event-Handler:

```
mre.WaitOne();
```

and in my Button2 Event-Handler:

```
mre.Set();
mre.Reset();
```

...but when I reach `WaitOne()` in my `Button1`-Event-Handler all my application freezes. Do you have any hints for me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you just set a variable on button 2 that the button 1 checks in a do while?

Comment: @PatrickGoode The loop in the Button1 click handler would prevent the Click event of Button2 from being processed (unless you added a call to `Application.DoEvents()` inside the loop; which is **NOT** the correct approach).  See my answer for one possible solution.

Comment: Well played.   Looking good with that Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark your Button1 click handler with [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) (before the void in the return type), then [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) a [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.7.2) that calls WaitOne():

```
private ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;

    for(int i = 1; i <=100; i++)
    {
        label1.Text = i.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(100);

        if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            label2.Text = "Press Button2 to Continue";
            await Task.Run(() => { 
                mre.WaitOne();
                mre.Reset();
            });
            label2.Text = "";
        }
    }

    button1.Enabled = true;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mre.Set();
}
```

Note that you can have multiple awaits inside the handler.  The first one obviously isn't necessary; it just slows down the loop so you can see the number changing.  Also note that you could change the delay to a ridiculously long amount and the form would still remain responsive!

Comment: Thank you for your help! Works perfect! To me (as a C# beginner), it seems to be a very good answer and clever coded!  Maybe, you want to add the code for Button2 as well? (Just for posterity: it's just a "mre.Set();" in the click-Handler). I inserted "mre.Reset()" after the "mre.WaitOne();" - maybe, you want to add it to your code above.

Comment: Comment: ```mre.Set(); mre.Reset();``` in botton2_Click-Handler routine didn't work for me. That's why I moved the ```mre.Reset();``` to a position right after the ```mre.WaitOne()``` command. I tried to edit your code accordingly, but my edit was rejected and I was asked to put that code-modification as a comment here. @Idle_Mind: if you agree with my proposal, please edit your code accordingly since they do not allow me to do it by myself.

Comment: It's a minor change that has slightly different behavior. With `Reset()` in buttton1, this allows you to click button2 **early**, and the loop will continue at the next stop without needing a click.  With `Reset()` in button2, clicking button2 early had no effect.  Just depends on what you're after, or if your actual problem is slightly different.

Comment: Right you are, Idle_Mind!  I did not think that thought quite to the end. Thank you for your excellent explainations!